# How to vertically align an item in flexbox rows

Tags: css, layout, sass, flexbox

I've heard flex box is one dimensional, just want to check if any method is available to align a particular flex box items (items with the same order) in a vertical line as in the following picture. (circles with 0 should be on the red vertical line) [image]

Answer (score 1):

As for your problem, you have to select the items which you want to move on the line using CSS pseudo-selectors. I have come up with the following solution.

## Solution

I hope the below code will help you.

```
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-left > div, .flex-right > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.flex-left>div:nth-child(2n+2){
  width: 200px;
}
.flex-right>div:nth-child(even){
  width: 200px;
}
.flex-right>div:nth-child(odd){
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: -20vw;
}
</style>

<div class="flex-container">
<div class="flex-left">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div> 
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-right">
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]